# How to make the value of one variable of one javascript function available in any other function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jquery-ui-datepicker, javascript-objects

I want the value of `someDate` to be available to my datepicker's minDate. At present I have kept it as new Date() for it to work, but in place of this I need someDate value. `someDate` logic is there in myFunction(). How can I achieve this?

**Declaring a global variable `someDate` didn't work.** It passed only the value for today's date. Changes made in `myFunction()` to `someDate` need to be incorporated in the Datepicker function.

Below is my code.

```js
function myFunction() 
    {
    var check = document.getElementById('check');
    var time = new Date().getHours();
    var currentday=new Date().getDate();
    alert(currentday);
    var someDate = new Date();
    var day=0;
    if(!check.checked && time>10)
    {
      alert(time);
      alert(check.checked);
      day=6-currentday-1;
    
      var someDate = new Date();
    
      if(day>=3)
       {
        alert(day);
        someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + 3); 
        alert(someDate);
       }
      else
       {
        alert(someDate);
        someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + 5); 
        alert('yayy!!');
       }
    }
    else if(check.checked && time<10)
    {
    alert('Time <10 and checked');
    }
    else if(!check.checked && time <10)
    {
    alert('Time <10 and UNchecked');
    }
    
    else
    {
    alert(time);
      alert(check.checked);
      day=6-currentday-1;
    
      
    
      if(day>1)
       {
        alert(day);
        someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + 1); 
        alert(someDate);
       }
    else
    {
    alert(day);
    someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + 3); 
        alert(someDate);
    }
    }
    
    
    
    }
    
    $(function() {
    
    alert(window.someDate);
                $( "#datepicker-5" ).datepicker({
    
                   beforeShowDay : function (date)
                   {
                      var dayOfWeek = date.getDay ();
                      // 0 : Sunday, 1 : Monday, ...
                      if (dayOfWeek == 0 || dayOfWeek == 6) return [false];
                      else return [true];
                   },
    
    minDate: someDate
    
                });
             });
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    
    
    <p id="demo"></p>             
          
    
    <p>Enter Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker-5" ></p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check" onclick="myFunction()" >
```

Comment: Global variables work for sure. Most likely you've shadowed your global in functions by declaring a local variable with the same name.

Comment: All you provided was how yo lnclude libraries in html code. Please provide some js code or at least whatever you tried. Other than that jqdatepicker has an option for mndate and you can set it as static valuable or change it via variable , like var date= the date you want

Comment: Hi Atilla, I have provided all the code that has the logic where the minDate is being set, as well as how in the jquery I need to place it. Please scroll down to see more of the code as the whole stuff is included.

Comment: Teemu, No I haven't , as i am using that same variable all throughout.

Comment: @Teemu No I haven't , as i am using that same variable all throughout.

Comment: @AtillaArdaAçıkgöz Hi Atilla, I have provided all the code that has the logic where the minDate is being set, as well as how in the jquery I need to place it. Please scroll down to see more of the code as the whole stuff is included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global namespace isn't required to solve this. You could put myFunction inside your document ready handler like this:

```
$(function(){
  var someDate;
  function myFunction(){ ... }

  //add the change handler to the checkbox
  $("#check").change(function(){
    myFunction();
  });
}
```

Note: this adds the checkbox change handler with jquery instead of in the dom so your input tag can just be:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" >
```

Comment: I followed this only and it worked, thanks for this! :)

Answer (score 1):

Even when you set `someDate` in the global scope the Datepicker doesn't know to use the new value. Datepicker *does* have a [refresh method](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-refresh) but in order to avoid using the global scope it would be much better to...

Use the [Datepicker option setter](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option) like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var someDate;

    // [Do the logic to decide value of someDate] 
    someDate = '+3d';     // three days from today, for example

    // Set the minDate option on the datePicker:
    $('#datepicker-5').datepicker('option', 'minDate', someDate);
}
```

Also note:

- You should remove `minDate: someDate` from your main datePicker initialisation.
- You might want to check the jQueryUI documentation for valid values for [minDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, though i have already found the answer to my problem.